# PyCharm Default Configuration

Tags: python, configuration, pycharm

Is there a way to run a script in PyCharm without it asking *which* configuration I want to use or for any configuration at all? I. e., set up a default configuration, so that whenever I open a script this gets used automatically?

Comment: Configure how? Which python version you want to use?

Comment: Any version. 3.7 for the moment. What I want is to not be asked WHICH configuration (permanent or temporary) I want to run if I run a script.

Comment: See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)